# Bootstrap 3 page layout and different styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am asking this question here to get some information and ideas from the professionals. My question is I just start to learn `Bootstrap 3.1` for my front end developments. So I have followed some basic tutorials regarding to the subject. With that tutorials, I found that the look and feels of every page layout have same structure and design. So I am afraid, Can we design advance and very different layout using `Bootstrap 3.1`?

Here I have attached a navigation bar. Someone can tell me, is it possible to design like this navigation bar using bootstrap 3.1?

[image]

I am not asking to someone to code this, just I ask this to make a strong sense about `bootstrap 3.1`.

hope someone pointed me out to the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: It is very important to understand that `Bootstrap` provides some pre-defined styles for elements, but it in no way limits the ways you can use the provided styles. You can simply make a div and style it using the `nav` and `navbar` bootstrap classes. There is a good chance that it will work the way you want, but usually you might need to define some other classes to override the default bootstrap ones and make it look exactly the way you want (The background color, for instance). I would suggest trying it and see what happens. Good Luck.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian, Thank you your comment. I appreciated it. If you have any links for advance tutorials of bootstrap send me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is easy to override any bootstrap styles you want.

It is designed to be usable out of the box, but also to provide good base styles in a logical way to be over ridden. The designers did not want to force you to use their styles.

If you use SASS or LESS, it will be easy. If you use the finished compiled CSS, it will be VERY tedious to edit.

I've built several apps entirely from Bootstrap 3, and most do not look like 'bootstrap' but use a ton of their base styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can I get some explanation about `SASS` and `LESS` and how its working? If you can give me some project links which you develop using bootstrap to understand its power for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, Yes you can. I don't think its that complicated to do. You can checkout the [Grid system here in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that meets your dimensions, it it doesn't meet then you always have your own custom grid made.

Hence you will have to do Media queries condition in your style-sheet on how will the site works on other devices.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```